# Foreach 4 items use a div, and then every other 4 items repeat another div

Tags: php

I am trying to create an image carousel, but that requires 2 seperate divs for the scroller, one active one, and then another which is not active but can be scrolled to...

This is what I'm trying to acomplish:

```
//the first 4 of a foreach
<div class="item active">
   <img src="<?php $images[$i]; ?>">
   <img src="<?php $images[$i]; ?>">
   <img src="<?php $images[$i]; ?>">
   <img src="<?php $images[$i]; ?>">
</div>

//the next 4 of a foreach
<div class="item">
  <img src="<?php $images[$i]; ?>">
  <img src="<?php $images[$i]; ?>">
  <img src="<?php $images[$i]; ?>">
  <img src="<?php $images[$i]; ?>">
</div><!-- /item -->

//now after every 4 repeat the <div class="item"> with the images inside, </div>
```

This is my foreach

```
<?php $i = 1; foreach(explode(",",$this->product->images) as $images): ?>
```

On each 4 I don't want the 4 divs to be repeated on the img inside the div.

I'm not sure how I will accomplish this?

Thanks to the posters. but now it's showing 5 instead of 4?

```
<div class="item active">
    <?php $i=1 ; foreach(explode( ",",$this->product->images) as $images): ?>
    <div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="thumb">
         <img src="<?php echo Config::get('URL') .'images/products/'.System::escape($this->product->username). '/item' .System::escape($this->product->id) .'/'. System::escape($images); ?>"></div>

     <?php if ($i % 4==0 ) { 

         echo '</div><div class="item">'; 
         echo '<div data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="'.$i. '" class="thumb"><img src="'.Config::get( 'URL') . 'images/products/'.System::escape($this->product->username). '/item' .System::escape($this->product->id) .'/'. System::escape($images).'"></div>'; 

     } $i+=1; endforeach; ?>
</div>
<!-- /item -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modulo operation to check, if your counter variable is the multiple of `4`:

```
if ($i % 4 == 0) {
   echo '</div><div>';
}
```

You just need to make sure that your `foreach` actually increases the value of `$i` on every iteration.

Alternatively you could reset `$i` back to `0` inside of the `if` body, so it always counts only to `4` and never higher. But I prefer the modulo solution, because that way you have an actual counter variable, not a fake one. :)

Comment: What about the first 4 because that needs a different div from the rest of the multiplies of 4

Comment: You need to start with a `<div>` outside of the foreach and end with a `</div>` after the loop. So this is a perfect match for your case. Inside of the loop you use the non-active class, outside the active one.

Comment: It's almost got it, but for some reason it's showing 5 instead of 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Simple approach , add  at start and also closing  at the end like

```
<?php
  $i=1; 
  foreach($arrayItems as $single){ 
    if($i%4 == 0){
?>
     <div class="Special">
<?php
    }
?>
  <div class="regular">Regular content</div>     
<?php
   if($i%4 == 0){
?>
    </div>
<?php
   }
   $i+=1; 
  }
?>
```

Comment: that seems to almost get it but it's showing 5 inside the div rather than 4 I've updated my op

Comment: `it's showing 5` Who is showing 5 ? Where its printed by u in code?